# Export C# Project as .EXE file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have a C# project in Visual Studio 2019 that I wish to export as a .EXE file. I have already run it in 'Release' Mode, but no .exe turns up in the 'bin' folder - just a '.deps', '.dll', '.pdb', '.runtimeconfig.dev' and a '.runtimeconfig'. I believe I am using a trial for the Enterprise version - does the trial allow this exporting?
Thanks.

Comment: What's the output type of the project ?

Comment: Default output is to bin\Release, not bin.

Comment: @RenanBarbosa: that's C++, not C#

Comment: Is this a .net core project? It certianly sounds like it if you have a `.runtimeconfig.dev` file. If so you would use something like `dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained`

Comment: To expand on what @auburg1 says, right-click on the project (in Solution Explorer) and choose Properties.  The Output Type property is on the Application page. You likely have Class Library there. If you want to build (not export, build) an application,  you need to have an appropriate Application type chosen. You may want to do some amount of starting over from scratch

Comment: @Flydog57: he just needs a main() method, not "some amount of starting over from scratch"

Comment: "I have already run it in 'Release' Mode" - you can really run it? Even if there's no exe file? How did you do that?

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: @stuartd Where would I write that command? Unlike VS Code, I don't actually have a terminal

Comment: @ThomasWeller Inside VS 2019 On the top bar I had 'Release' and 'Any CPU' selected and just clicked on the green 'play' button to run.

Comment: In the normal Windows command window (cmd.exe)

Comment: A .NETCore project creates a DLL, not an EXE.  Ready to execute with dotnet.exe.  Just like java.exe executes a Java program, python.exe executes a Python program, etc.  Google ".net core self-contained app" to learn more.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks, that works! You can write that as a full answer so I can accept it if you want :)

Comment: @stuartd Is there any way to incorporate this directly into VS 2019 instead of having to save this instruction somewhere and loading up a cmd every time?

Comment: You could add it to the post-build event in the project file but note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55169309/43846) _"Add the --no-build parameter to dotnet publish in your post-build event. By default, dotnet publish will run a build, which will trigger post-build events, which will then try to publish again, which will cause an infinite loop that appears to make the build hang."_

Comment: Per `auburg` and `Flydog57`'s comments, you need to change the default output type.  More info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6866648/361842.  This is the same result as `Stuartd`'s answer, only that's a command line argument rather than set through the project's config.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you have a library project as part of the solution and you are looking in the library's bin folder for the exe. It will not be there if that is the case. You will only find the dll in that bin folder.

1 - Right Click your project that youre expecting the output to be an EXE
[image: step 1]

2 - Click "Open Folder in File Explorer"
[image: step 2]

3 - you should see a bin folder here, navigate in and you'll find your Release and Debug folders.

Comment: Thanks, but as I explained I already did that but there were no .exe files. Luckily @stuartd had the solution, and thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments:

### Terminology

The process of converting source code to a binary (exe, dll, etc) is called `compiling` or `building` the code, rather than `exporting` it.

### Command Line

To build the code from the command line you can run [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish):

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained
```

By targeting the Windows platform (set by the `-r` / `--runtime` parameter) a program will become an executable.  Other platforms don't use `exe` files; so a non runtime specific build would create a `dll` as that can be used on a variety of platforms.

### CS Project File

- Open your project's `.csproj` file in an editor.
- Amend file's `OutputType` to `WinExe` (Windows Application) or `Exe` (Console Application).

### IDE UI

You can update the CS Project File by editing it directly, or by navigating the to the relevant settings in your IDE.  Assuming that's Visual Studio:

- Open the `Solution Explorer` window
- Right-click on the project & click `Properties`
- Select the `Application` section
- Amend the `Output Type` property to `Windows Application` or `Console Application`.

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio 2019 IDE showing the above forms]